# Example of $postLink() in components

Tags: angularjs

I can't find any example of `$postLink()` from AngularJS [components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component), part **Components have a well-defined lifecycle**. Can you please provide a simple example just of the method implented in a controller where I could realize how to manipulate DOM?

The only article explaining `$postLink()` a little is http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2016/03/29/exploring-angular-1.5-lifecycle-hooks.html .

It seems like that there is no argument in `$postLink()`. Thus I would inject `$element` and modify the DOM.

Answer (score 11):

So the usage is simple:

```
function Controller($element) {
        var self = this;

        self.$postLink = $postLink;

        function $postLink() {
            $element.attr("mymymy", "xxxxxx");
        }
}
```

Then let's say my component name is **myComponent** and using an inspector of a browser you could see a modified tag with an added attribute from above: `<my-component mymymy="xxxxxx"></my-component>`.